# Return dispersion calculation in R

Tags: r, return

I would like to calculate the return dispersion over a long period of time. The formula I use is the formula for the equal weighted standard deviation ([see here](http://i62.tinypic.com/de0adt.png)). I tried to use the `sd()` and `apply()` function, but it did not work.

Formula:

`r(i,t) are i=4 stock returns (so n=4) at time (t)`

`R(SMI,t)` is the index at time `(t)`

```
                NOVARTIS R    NESTLE R       ROCHE    UBS GROUP
    2005-07-18  1.11200510 -0.14716706    -0.4210533 -0.28876340
    2005-07-19  0.23668650 -0.22115748    -0.3623192  0.67176884
    2005-07-20  0.07877117 -0.44378771     4.0313698 -0.47844392
    2005-07-21 -0.55270571 -0.37133351    -0.8754068  0.28604262
    2005-07-22 -0.23781224 -0.07443246     0.2926546  0.00000000
    2005-07-25  0.23781224  0.74184316     0.4082829 -0.09525666
```

This is my index

```
SMI
2005-07-18 -0.01077012
2005-07-19  0.53767147
2005-07-20 -0.02208674
2005-07-21 -0.10192245
2005-07-22  0.01653908
2005-07-25  0.03050783
```

Now I want to calculate the RD for every time (t), so I get a timeseries for all RDs.

What functions, loops or other techniques should I look at? I do not want to do it by hand because the formula may be applied to bigger dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up my own sample data because it was easier but I think this is what you're after.  It uses data.table and reshape2 for the heavy lifting.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

#make fake data
set.seed(100)
rit<-data.table(dATE=as.POSIXct('2005-07-18')+(60*60*24*0:5),
                stock1=runif(6,-1,1),
                stock2=runif(6,-1,1),
                stock3=runif(6,-1,1),
                stock4=runif(6,-1,1))

smi<-data.table(dATE=as.POSIXct('2005-07-18')+(60*60*24*0:5),smi=runif(6,-1,1))


#to convert from a matrix like object 
#(I can't quickly figure out how to pull POSIXct out of ts object
#so it's hard coded dates but will still work)

rit<-data.table(your_rit_object)
rit[,dATE=seq(from=as.POSIXct('2005-07-18'), to=as.POSIXct('2005-07-25'),by='days')

smi<-data.table(your_smi_object)
smi[,dATE=seq(from=as.POSIXct('2005-07-18'), to=as.POSIXct('2005-07-25'),by='days')

#melt table from wide to long
ritmelt<-melt(rit,id.vars="dATE")
#combine with smi table
ritmeltsmi<-merge(ritmelt,smi,by='dATE')
#implement formula
ritmeltsmi[,sqrt(sum((value-smi)^2))/.N,by=dATE]
#if you want to name the new column you could do this instead
#ritmeltsmi[,list(RD=sqrt(sum((value-smi)^2))/.N),by=dATE]
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the right approach. You forgot to take the square root <ritmeltsmi[,sqrt(sum((value-smi)^2)/.N),by=dATE]>, but this is not a big deal. The problem now I get is that, in your example which worked well you used "data.table" "data.frame" class. My class is "time.series". So I converted it with the "as.data.frame" function also to data class. But the very first column (where the date is) is not recognized or I am not able to change the name. So I can not assign the <id.vars> im "melt" function and I get error message <Error: id variables not found in data: dATE>.

Comment: @Sogomon see the edit for how to convert to data.table.